# How Do I Annotate Charts in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, scripting, charts

I've got a MATLAB script that is called every half hour to build a chart that is placed on my webpage:

```
load ~/emailAnalysis/results.txt
temp = results(:,3)-1238370000;
h=plot(temp,results(:,1))
xlim([0,max(temp)-1])
ylim([0 max(results(:,1))])
set(gca,'XTick',[1:86400*7:(86400*max(temp))+1])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[1:1:100])
set(gca,'XGrid','on')
title('Size of inbox over time')
xlabel('Time (Weeks)')
ylabel('Emails')
set(h,'LineWidth',2)
print -djpeg /www/home/joseph/inboxlongterm.jpeg
exit
```

I'd like to be able to annotate the chart with the occasional text comment (for example, some text centered on a particular x,y coordinate saying "On holiday" or similar).

I had a bit of a Google and didn't get very far at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add text to a figure at coordinates x,y, use the command

```
text(x,y,'string')
```

If you want the text *centred* on x,y, try:

```
h = text(x,y,'string')
set(h,'HorizontalAlignment','center')
```

You can also add arrows or lines to connect the text to a point on a graph using the *annotation* function.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like MATLAB allows programmatic annotations with [the `annotation()` function](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/annotation.html).

[alt text http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/annotationex1.gif](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/annotationex1.gif)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [text](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) function

```
text(x,y,'string')
```

where x,y are the coordinates. If you want to output text with tex symbols you can combine the [texlabel](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/texlabel.html) function with the text function

```
text(x,y, texlabel('lambda12^(3/2)/pi - pi*delta^(2/3)'))
```